# Adjusting a Unix shell script to create a CSV from a log file

Tags: shell

I have a Unix shell script which generates output from a log.

```
for i in HistSimBasislieferung hedgeAccountingF4PublicSend;do
  report1=$(echo -n $i:)
  date1=$(grep -e $i $PALME_CONF | grep "The job finished" | tail -1 | awk '{print $1,$2}'|\<br/> sed 's/^.\(.*\).$/\1/')
  final="$report1 $date1"
  echo "$final"
done
```

At the moment the output looks like this:

```
HistSimBasislieferung 2015-03-11 01:03:02
hedgeAccountingF4PublicSend 2015-03-11 00:16:34
```

But what I want is something like this:

```
HistSimBasislieferung,hedgeAccountingF4PublicSend
2015-03-11 01:03:02,2015-03-11 00:16:34
```

Do you have any suggestions on how this could be done?

---

I did it the way you suggested:

```
   for i in HistSimBasislieferung hedgeAccountingF4PublicSend;do
           echo -n $i > report_log
           grep -e $i $PALME_CONF | grep "The job finished" | tail -1 | awk '{print $1,$2}' | sed 's/^.\(.*\).$/\1/' > date_log

   done
   cat < report_log | xargs echo | tr ' ' ',';
   cat < date_log | xargs echo | tr ' ' ',';
   echo "" > report_log; echo "" > date_log
```

but the output gave:

```
hedgeAccountingF4PublicSend2015-03-11,00:16:34    
I need it like this:  
HistSimBasislieferung,hedgeAccountingF4PublicSend,  
2015-03-11 03:05:40,2015-03-11 02:12:19,
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a loop script, so it will overwrite the variable every loop.  My suggestion here, is to create logfile for the "report" and a logfile for "date" too (append log).

At the end of your script (right below the "done" line), execute the command below:

```
cat <\report_log_file> | xargs echo | tr ' ' ',';
cat <\date_log_file> | xargs echo | | tr ' ' ','
```

or create another loop script.

```
for i in <\report_log_file> <\date_log_file>; do
   cat $i | xargs echo | tr ' ' ',';
done
```

then, clear the logfiles:

```
echo "" > report_log_file; echo "" > date_log_file
```

Comment: Hi David  for i in HistSimBasislieferung hedgeAccountingF4PublicSend;do
           echo -n $i > report_log
           grep -e $i $PALME_CONF | grep "The job finished" | tail -1 | awk '{print $1,$2}' | sed 's/^.\(.*\).$/\1/' > date_log

   done
   cat < report_log | xargs echo | tr ' ' ',';
   cat < date_log | xargs echo | tr ' ' ',';
   echo "" > report_log; echo "" > date_log
gives  hedgeAccountingF4PublicSend2015-03-11,00:16:34

Answer (score 0):

This one liner might look ugly but I think it does the job (if I understand your use case correctly).

```
your_shell_script.sh  | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/,$/\n/'; your_shell_script.sh | cut -d ' ' -f '2-' | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/,$/\n/'
```